# Compilation QT Creator project using classic terminal and gcc/g++

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm tired searching in internet.
I created a klient-serwer program, which shut down computer just by their IP's on specific port.I made whole thing in C, everything works perfectly, i'm compiling my project using gcc with -Wall option and I've got a clear results.
But I had to create GUI so i decided to use QT Creator IDE, I transfered code from C into C++ and i made GUI. Program works but I have to compile this using g++ with -Wall option.
Thing is, I cannot compile anything.

```
g++ my_project.cpp -o mypro -Wall

ERROR: fatal error: QMainWindow: directory don't exist (in my native language)
compilation terminated
(same with other source files)
```

Any ideas?
It's propably very easy, but believe me, I want to compile this and go to sleep. Cheers

Comment: In the Qt world you should be using .pro files to configure your compilation steps, using qmake to process the .pro files, and then using 'make' on the resulting makefile from qmake to actually compile everything. The makefile will handle gcc/g++ for you.  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html

Comment: You can [set compiler arguments](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cxxflags) in Qt Creator. Is there a reason why you can't use Creator?

Comment: @Mitch my techear wants to see it this way if there's no warnings

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use qmake? First, you can edit your *.pro file and add any compiler flags you wish (see Mitch's comment). Then, if you execute `qmake` and then `make`, it will show you a sequence of compilation commands with proper flags, linker and include paths and so on. After that you can just reproduce that commands manually if your teacher wants so.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the compiler is trying to open `QMainWindow` as if it was a directory (if the translation is correct) or at least failing to locate where the include files for Qt are. You probably need to provide some -I option to hint the compiler as to where the Qt headers are, and make sure that the `#include` directives are correct in your code.

Comment: Correct translation: no such file or directory.
How to use these -l hints?

Comment: @krzakov: Assuming that the Qt headers are installed in `/some/path` then you can use `-I/some/path` in the command line to instruct the compiler that it should also search for headers inside that directory.

Comment: @krzakov: *don't work* is a very imprecise description of what is happening. What is the exact error, what are the options in the command line, where are the Qt headers?...